# Authorization doesn't work when using Spring boot rest api using oauth2 , Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak

I am trying to use oauth2 to do authentication and authorization for rest api.
with the rest api url as "/users" and the role "userrole" is defined in keycloak.

I have used used keycloak for jwt access token. Authentication is working fine but Authorization is not working.

If I specify hasRole I always get forbidden error.
But if I will remove hasRole authentication works as expected.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
    private String jwtSetUri;

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.cors().and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
              .authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers("/users").hasRole("userrole").antMatchers("/users").authenticated()
                .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt() ;

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you constructing the GrantedAuthorities upon successful Authentication ? Do you have ROLE_userrole as a GrantedAuthority for the user ?

Comment: As I am using keycloak , I have created the role called as "userrole"  under client and realm both and assigned it to the user .

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak provides an example with KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter . There could be a rolename mismatch due to which the Authorization fails

Comment: I am not using KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.